# How to render Django flat pages as plain text with line breaks (no html tags allowed)

Tags: python, html, django

We have a continuing need to update an ads.txt file that lives at the root of a Django project.  The current method to update this file is ftp it and a “service nginx restart” performed by a developer.  We want to now do this with a flat page and template and simply have a “non-developer” cut and paste the contents of the ads.txt file into the Content: field via the Django administration app, save and all should be well.  The issue is the line breaks do not render unless we add html `<br>` tags.  This causes the ads.txt file to not pass validation tests since no html is allowed, only plain text.  How can we accomplish this?
The template is simply

```
{{ flatpage.content }}
```

Trying

```
{{ flatpage.content|linebreaks }}
```

causes html tags to be inserted into the rendered page and fails the ads.txt test.  We’ve tried various combinations such as

```
(r'^ads_txt/$', 'media.views.custom_header')
```

in urls.py and

```
def custom_header(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
```

in views.py to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `striptags` tag?

```
{{ flatpage.content|linebreaks|striptags }}
```

Comment: No, but I will and let you know.  Thanks!

Comment: Nope, that didn't work... ads.txt still renders without line breaks.